# find an import in code with regular expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have an import error somewhere in my code but can't find it. I can use the search function in my editor (sublime text) to search for a regular expression in all the files inside the project. So I would like to search for the terms 'import' and 'views' with anything in between or before / after, I just want to match any line that contains these two words.

Comment: Please give some input example

Comment: what programming lang do you use?

Comment: I use python. The input could be something like 'from module.views import whatever' or 'from package.module import views'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with 'Sublime Text', but the following `regex` works well in 'Notepad++':

```
(.*)(import)(.*)(views)(.*)
```

Now, in the line matched, `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4` and `$5` may be used to refer to the text before "import", "import", the text between "import" and "views", "views" and the text after "views" respectively.

### EDIT - 1

It works well with 'Sublime Text' as well.

For example, for the text,

```
asdf1234 ..import.fghj4567 views...hjkl7890
```

Find What (as above):

```
(.*)(import)(.*)(views)(.*)
```

Replace With:

```
$2, $4, $5, $3, $1
```

Result:

```
import, views, ...hjkl7890, .fghj4567 , asdf1234 ..
```

---

---

For the text,

```
asdf1234 views fghj4567 import hjkl7890
```

Find What (as above):

```
(.*)(views)(.*)(import)(.*)
```

Replace With:

```
$2, $4, $5, $3, $1
```

Result:

```
views, import,  hjkl7890,  fghj4567 , asdf1234
```

### EDIT - 2

It seems to be working well for me though:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution and it returns the lines where the two words are present but with spaces around them. In most cases these terms will be surrounded with dots too, or dots and spaces.

Comment: @Bastian: Could you provide an example of a line this fails at?

Comment: I failed to return things like 'from project.package.views import module' with this solution.

Comment: @Bastian: Oh? With the `regex` `(.*)(views)(.*)(import)(.*)`, it works just fine for me.

Comment: @Bastian: Are you interested in a replace or just search? If you just want to search, you can use the single `regex` as follows: `(.*views.*import.*)|(.*import.*views.*)`.

Comment: I just want to search for debug purposes. That precise expression in my case returns 0 result.

Comment: @Bastian: I've added a screenshot. it seems to work well for me at least for the given test case.

Comment: Oh well it most certainly works. I restarted Sublime Text and tried again but as it performs the search it suddenly crashes so I can't really tell. I will try on another system. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I must add that I do not perform the search in a single page but the entire project thus the resource intensive process could explain the long delay / crash.